# Get the latest data of duplicated entries in MYSQL

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I have a mysql table that contains all the subscribed plan by users.
I am trying to create a SELECT statement that will allow me to select for a particular user from the table. Also, if that user have duplicated entries, it will get the latest date of all.

For example, I want to look for John from the table and the date I should get is 2015-09-10.

```
Subscribed table
ID   FirstName   Date
-------------------------------
1   John        2015-05-30
2   Mary        2014-01-10
3   John        2015-09-10
4   John        2015-03-15
5   Loen        2013-12-11
```

How should I go about creating the SELECT statement to above the result?

Comment: `ORDER BY \`DATE\` DESC LIMIT 1`

Comment: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/44fe5/2 check this

Comment: Check out http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ec5d1/1 and confirm whether it answers your query. Accept corresponding answer if it does.

Answer (score 1):

If you just need the first one, you can use `LIMIT` in conjunction with `ORDER BY`:

```sql
SELECT * FROM `Subscribed`
  WHERE `FirstName` = 'John' -- Get the name John.
  ORDER BY `Date` DESC       -- Sort results in descending order by Date.
  LIMIT 1                    -- Limit the results to one.
```

The result will be ordered by date in descending order, and the `LIMIT 1` gives out the first row.

Or to be precise, you can also use Grouping Functions if you need more than one row.

```
SELECT `FirstName`, MAX(`Date`) FROM `Subscribed`
  WHERE `FirstName` = 'John'
  GROUP BY `FirstName`
```

**Fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ebb90/1**

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT FirstName, max(Date) FROM yourTable
WHERE FirstName = 'John'
```

also you can use `group by` to take the result for all persons not just `John`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this for all users:

```
select s.*
from subscribed s join
     (select firstname, max(date) as maxd
      from subscribed
      group by firstname
     ) ss
     on ss.firstname = s.firstname and ss.maxd = s.date;
```

Answer (score 0):

Query for required output:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM `Subscribed`
       ORDER BY `DATE` DESC) t group by firstName
```

Alternatively, you can use MAX and GROUP BY

```
SELECT firstName, MAX(date) FROM `Subscribed`

group by firstName
```

Verify output here : http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ec5d1/1

Output:

```
id  firstName   date
3   John        September, 10 2015 00:00:00
2   Mary        January, 10 2014 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

Gordeon Linoff has good answer, if your ID is a primary key and always grow on time as well, you can do this SQL for better speed:

```
SELECT s.*
FROM subscribed s, 
    (SELECT FirstName, max(ID) maxID FROM subscribed GROUP BY 1) AS ss
WHERE s.ID = ss.maxID;
```